# Self-referencing model MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a component that have a list of subcomponents:

```
public class Componente
    {
        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual string NameComp { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Subcomponent> Subcomponents { get; set; }
}

public class Subcomponent
    {
        public virtual int SubcomponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }

        public virtual string NameSub { get; set; }

        public virtual Component CompSub { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Subcomponent> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Then i have a view that shows the components, their subcomponents and in the future the subsubcomponents and so on.

```
<table>
 ...

        if (item.Subcomponents.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var x in item.Subcomponents)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.NameSub)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Create Subcomponent", "CreateMoreSubcomponents", "Subcomponent", new { id = x.SubcomponentId }, null)

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }

</table>
```

And the create method:

```
public ActionResult CreateMoreSubcomponents(int id)
        {
            var x = db.Subcomponents.FirstOrDefault(e => e.SubcomponentId == id);

            if (x == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var subcomponent = new Subcomponent()
            {
                ParentId = x.SubcomponentId
            };

            return View("CreateMoreSubcomponents", subcomponent);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateMoreSubcomponents(Subcomponent subcomponent)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Subcomponents.Add(subcomponent);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ...
            }
```

The goal is to have subsubcomponents, subsubsubcomponents and so on. But the code that i show here is not working, it gives an error in the db.SaveChanges(); because it asks for the componentId but i don't know what do i have to change. What do i need to change or do? Thanks

Comment: You have to provide some mapping so EF knows about the recursive relationship AND you have to tell EF to provide the value for the identifier (or you have to do it). For the former map it to a database generated column Identity, for the later manually provide new Ids for each component and referencing child/parent components.

Comment: Suggest you look at [this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/255/entity-framework-recipe-hierarchical-data-management)